# Algorithm for tree-like connections?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

The thing is I need to create an unidimensional array that represents a certain number of objects.
Those objects are organized as shown in the picture.
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sddQy.jpg)

And I have to be able to tell wich one is conected to.
The number of objects is the only thing given.

Is there any algorithm of some sort to do this?

Comment: Please provide your effort(s) thus far (e.g., post your code and/or describe the algorithms you have considered thus far). Without this, it is difficult for others to offer guidance or suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Yes there is. What have you tried? Where did things go wrong?  Please review the welcome tutorial for SO, and [How to ask...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of organization is often used to implement heaps in arrays: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-representation-of-binary-heap/

You just put the objects into the array in level order (top 1 first, then the 2 from level 2, then the 4 from level 3, etc.).

Assuming 0-based indexing, then, the object in **array[i]** has children **array[2*i+1]** and **array[2*i+2]**.

If your array starts at **[1]**, then the object in **array[i]** has children **array[2*i]** and **array[2*i+1]**